# Rails error: uninitialized constant User::Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

When you see an error like "uninitialized constant User::Nil" what does that mean?

I think it has something to do with my Authorization model connecting with a User model... I'm setting up sign in through FB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have mistakenly capitalized `nil` somewhere.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    Nil
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# => NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Nil
```